# Get value of pseudo classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-class

```
.a:before {
  content: 'b';
  display: table;
      }
```

How can I get content value of class 'a'? I was try:

```
`var b = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('a'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content');`
```

It return me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

Comment: think you missed the point... querySelector('.a')

Comment: or an extra `.` in his CSS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have pointed out, you're missing a dot before `a` in your selector. The correct code should look like this:

```js
var text = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.a'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
alert(text);
```

```css
.a:before {
  content: 'b';
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

As a general debugging strategy, it's a good idea to split longer statements in smaller parts to identify what is wrong in your code.
For example, here you could rewrite your JavaScript as:

```
var a = document.querySelector('a');
var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(a, ':before');
var content = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('content');
```

This way, we see immediately that `a`, the value assigned in the first statement, is actually `null`, and that explains the TypeError in the second statement.
This reduces the problem to what is wrong in `document.querySelector('a')`?, which is fairly easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

To access the content property of a css pseudo-class like this:

```
.a::before {
  content: 'b';
  display: table;
}
```

you can use this javascript:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.a'),':before').getPropertyValue('content');
```

make sure css the pseudo-class in css has `::` and querySelector uses the a point `('.a')`

Here's a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hqdmjp40/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)